# Login Persistance in Firebase (V9)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been reading the user documentation for browser login Persistence at Google [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#web-version-9). However its not clear enough, on what I should be doing for v9. Briefly here's what I understood. There are three types of persistence's: Per Session, Per Browser, and None. So now what I wanted to do was set Persistence for "per Browser". I saw two functions being used, one is `inMemoryPersistence` which I assumed to be per Browser and the other to be `browserSessionPersistence` which i assumed to be "per Session". However even after trying with both of them, after closing the tab and reopening its sends me to the login page.

```js
const auth = getAuth();
setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
    // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
    // if a user forgets to sign out.
    // ...
    // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

My code is just the same as what's provided in the docs, with `browserSessionPersistance` being one of two parameters I tried.
So my question is:

1. Is my understanding of the 3 Types Correct?
2. If it is, then why isn't browser persistence working?

(Also I'm using Vanilla Javascript with Modular Import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to persist auth state and required explicit logout, use `browserLocalPersistence`.

| Version V8 `firebase.auth.Auth` | Version V9 | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Persistence.LOCAL` | `browserLocalPersistence` | Explit logout required |
| `Persistence.SESSION` | `browserSessionPersistence` | current session or tab, cleared when closed |
| `Persistence.NONE` | `inMemoryPersistence` | *in memory*, not persisted, cleared when page is refreshed |

Also checkout [Persistence interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.persistence) in the documentation.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. It worked like a charm. Could you tell the source of this, because i couldn't find it in the docs for v9. I now realize that inMemory means the temp storage and not the browser storage...

Comment: @mrtechtroid you can find it in the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.persistence) or by hovering on the imports in your IDE like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgj5w.png).