Fastify CORS error when running firebase emulator locally
I am experiencing some cors error while using fastify and firebase emulator locally:
signin:1 Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/<redacted>/asia-southeast1/hello/api/v1/session_login' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
Fastify Backend
server.register(cors, {
    origin: true,
    methods: ["GET", "PUT", "PATCH", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    credentials: true,
});

server.register(singleClientAndContact, { prefix: API_V1 });

exports.hello = onRequest(
    {
        secrets: [DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD],
        cors: true,
        region: "asia-southeast1",
    },

    async (req, res) => {
        await server.ready();
        server.server.emit("request", req, res);
    }
);

React frontend:
    const handleGoogle = async () => {
        const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            username,
            password
        );

        const idToken = await getIdToken(userCredential.user);
        const res = await postIdTokenToSessionLogin(idToken);

        setUsername("");
        setPassword("");

        if (res.ok) {
            return navigate("/client_management", { replace: true });
        }
    };

async function postIdTokenToSessionLogin(idToken: string) {
    return await fetch(`${DOMAIN}/api/v1/session_login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ idToken }),
        credentials: "include",
    });
}

firebase.json
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "backend",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log",
        "*.local"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "public": "frontend/dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}


What I have tried
I have also set the firebase function's permissions to allUsers for the Cloud Invoker Function permissions.
I have also initialized firebase to connect to the emulator:
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
const functions = getFunctions(getApp(), "asia-southeast1");
setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75264880/login-persistance-in-firebase-v9
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);

I noticed that the issue only happens when credentials: "include" is set. Not sure what I am missing here. Appreciate any help on this.
